# When and why do i need a 's' flag for sorting by a column

Tags: bash, sorting, multiple-columns

i was trying to sort a file by the first column, not changing the order of the second column if first column have same value,

```
$ cat test
1   4
1   3
1   2   
1   1
3   3
2   1
2   2
2   3
```

desire output:

```
1   4
1   3
1   2   
1   1
2   1
2   2
2   3
3   3
```

This work only when i use `sort test -s -k1,1`.

The following all changes the order of the second column:

```
sort test
sort test -k1
sort test -k1,1
sort test -s -k1

1   1
1   2   
1   3
1   4
2   1
2   2
2   3
3   3
```

why do i need to use `-s` together with `-k1,1` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `man sort`:

> -s, --stable
>                 stabilize sort by disabling last-resort comparison

In other words, if `sort` finds that two lines have equal keys, it will compare the entire lines to sort them. You disabled this last comparison with `-s` so you kept the original order.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability

Comment: then what is the difference of -k1,1 and -k1 ?

Comment: @once `-k` allows you to define the position of the key `sort` will use from the line as `-k start,end`. `-k1,1` says "sort using as key only the first field", `-k1` says "sort using as key the sub-line from the first field to the end of the line" since the default stop position is the end of the line. This is why in your example you need `-k1,1` and not `-k1`. I suggest you read the manual of `sort`: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sort.1.html

Comment: i read the manual for both flags, just cant make it clear why things not work when using -k1,1  "sort using as key only the first field", yet still need an addition -s stable flag for this situation

Comment: @once No matter what key you choose, the default behavior of `sort` is that if two keys are identical it will use a last-resort comparison to decide how to sort, probably because it is useful in most cases. But forget about that particular behavior, a sorting algorithm will not necessary preserve the original order, you need to choose one that does in your case. To do this with `sort`, you need the `-s` or `--stable` option.